# One graph take over space when the other is Visibility.Collapsed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface

This is C# WPF and xaml. I have main window, and I have two graphs that share this window. They are vertically arranged. They both have same width as the main window. However, I want the first graph to fill the entire window (except for some margin on the top of the window) when the second one is collapsed, and I want them to share the height (each with Height = (Height of Window)/2 ) when both are visible.

Here is what I tried in xaml, not successful though:

```
<Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <d3:ChartPlotter  Grid.Row="0" Name ="timeDomainPlotter" >
                </d3:ChartPlotter>
                <d3:ChartPlotter  Grid.Row="1" Name ="freqDomainPlotter" >
                </d3:ChartPlotter>
            </Grid>
```

The first window does not take over the second window's space when the second one is Visibility.Collapsed.
How should I do this? Thanks.

Update:
Converter code in pop up window where there are two graphs:

```
 public class VisibilityToHeightConverter : IValueConverter
        {
            public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {
                GridLength height = new GridLength();

                var visiblity = (Visibility)value;
                switch (visiblity)
                {
                    case Visibility.Collapsed:
                        height = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Auto);
                        break;
                    case Visibility.Visible:
                        height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
                        break;
                    case Visibility.Hidden:
                        height = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Auto);
                        break;
                }

                return height;
            }

            public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Interaction logic for SignalStatsDisplay.xaml
        /// </summary>
        public partial class SignalStatsDisplay : Window
        {
```

xaml for pop up window:

```
<Window x:Class="FileWatcherCaller.View.SignalStatsDisplay"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d3="http://research.microsoft.com/DynamicDataDisplay/1.0"
   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FileWatcherCaller.View"
    Title="Real Time Signal Display" Height="409" Width="1200">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:VisibilityToHeightConverter x:Key="VisToHeightConv"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid> 
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="pixVal" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Checked="checkBox1_Checked">Pixel Value</CheckBox>
                <CheckBox Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="roiMean" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">ROI Mean</CheckBox>
                <CheckBox Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="roiStd" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Checked="roiStd_Checked">ROI Std</CheckBox>
            </StackPanel>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=timeDomainPlotter, Path=Visibility, Converter={StaticResource VisToHeightConv}}" Name="RowOne" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=freqDomainPlotter, Path=Visibility, Converter={StaticResource VisToHeightConv}}" Name="RowTwo" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <d3:ChartPlotter  Grid.Row="0" Name ="timeDomainPlotter" >
                </d3:ChartPlotter>
                <d3:ChartPlotter  Grid.Row="1" Name ="freqDomainPlotter" >
                </d3:ChartPlotter>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In main window, how the Visibility of two graphs are initialized:

```
public void StartWatch()
        {
            if (_fileWatcher != null)
            {
                _fileWatcher.Dispose();
                _fileWatcher = null;
            }
            if (InitWatcher())
            {
                this._fileWatcher.Start();
                this.ButtonStart.IsEnabled = false;
                this.ButtonStop.IsEnabled = true;
            }

             _signalDisplay = new SignalStatsDisplay();

            if (_signalDisplay.Visibility != Visibility.Visible)
            {
                _signalDisplay.Show();
                _signalDisplay.timeDomainPlotter.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                _signalDisplay.freqDomainPlotter.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }


        }
```

For Kevin's sulution, I have the xaml for the pop up window:

```
<Window x:Class="FileWatcherCaller.View.SignalStatsDisplay"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d3="http://research.microsoft.com/DynamicDataDisplay/1.0"
    Title="Real Time Signal Display" Height="409" Width="1200">

    <Grid> 
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="pixVal" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Checked="checkBox1_Checked">Pixel Value</CheckBox>
                <CheckBox Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="roiMean" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">ROI Mean</CheckBox>
                <CheckBox Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="roiStd" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Checked="roiStd_Checked">ROI Std</CheckBox>
            </StackPanel>            
            <UniformGrid Columns="1">
                <d3:ChartPlotter Name ="timeDomainPlotter" >
                </d3:ChartPlotter>
                <d3:ChartPlotter Name ="freqDomainPlotter" >
                </d3:ChartPlotter>
            </UniformGrid>          
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

But still, it is not maximize the top D3 graph as expected. It is still takes only half of the window. Anything I should do in the behind code?

Comment: Your rowdefinititions are still bound to my example rectangles. Change it to: <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=timeDomainPlotter, Path=Visibility, Converter={StaticResource VisToHeightConv}}" Name="RowOne" />
    <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=freqDomainPlotter, Path=Visibility, Converter={StaticResource VisToHeightConv}}" Name="RowTwo" />

Comment: Yeah, I changed that actually, but not working. The converter is responding, but the height of the D3 plotter remains half of the windows. It does not occupy the entire windows as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Window x:Class="FileWatcherCaller.View.SignalStatsDisplay"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d3="http://research.microsoft.com/DynamicDataDisplay/1.0"
    Title="Real Time Signal Display" Height="409" Width="1200">

    <Grid> 
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0">
            <CheckBox Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="pixVal" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Checked="checkBox1_Checked">Pixel Value</CheckBox>
            <CheckBox Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="roiMean" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">ROI Mean</CheckBox>
            <CheckBox Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="roiStd" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Checked="roiStd_Checked">ROI Std</CheckBox>
        </StackPanel>            
        <UniformGrid Columns="1" Grid.Row="1">
            <d3:ChartPlotter Name ="timeDomainPlotter" >
            </d3:ChartPlotter>
            <d3:ChartPlotter Name ="freqDomainPlotter" >
            </d3:ChartPlotter>
        </UniformGrid>  
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2):

`UniformGrid` works the way you're looking for (as long as you don't want the user to resize the two sections)

```
<UniformGrid Columns="1">
<TextBox Visibility="Collapsed">Hello</TextBox>
<TextBox Visibility="Visible">Goodbye</TextBox>
</UniformGrid>
```

For something more flexible, I think you're going to have to write some code.

Comment: This lays out the two textboxes horizontally...and if you specify Rows="2" the visible textbox only takes up half the space.

Comment: Missed the horizontal vs. vertical approach.  You have to specify Columns=1, not Rows=2 (UniformGrid is weird...)

Comment: For Kevin's solution, I got "Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Research.DynamicDataDisplay.ChartPlotter' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.RowDefinition'. Error at object 'Microsoft.Research.DynamicDataDisplay.ChartPlotter' in markup file 'FileWatcherCaller;component/view/signalstatsdisplay.xaml'."

Comment: <UniformGrid Columns="1">
            <d3:ChartPlotter />
            <d3:ChartPlotter />
</UniformGrid> works fine for me. The Grid.Row property is unnecessary.

Comment: ........it is still not working, although I no longer get the error. I am posting my pop up window xaml in the original thread.

Comment: Did you actually try with D3 plotter?

Comment: Yes, I see your problem now. The vertical stackpanel will resize its children when one is collapsed. It needs to be replaced with a two row grid. Edit incoming...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24786/discussion-between-narohi-and-nick-tsui)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example app that has your desired behavior:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:VisibilityToHeightConverter x:Key="VisToHeightConv"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=rctTop, Path=Visibility, Converter={StaticResource VisToHeightConv}}" Name="RowOne" />
            <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=rctBottom, Path=Visibility, Converter={StaticResource VisToHeightConv}}" Name="RowTwo" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Fill="Black" Name="rctTop" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Red" Name="rctBottom" Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
public class VisibilityToHeightConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        GridLength height = new GridLength();

        var visiblity = (Visibility)value;
        switch(visiblity)
        {
            case Visibility.Collapsed:
                height = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Auto);
                break;
            case Visibility.Visible:
                height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
                break;
            case Visibility.Hidden:
                height = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Auto);
                break;
        }

        return height;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Let us know if any part of this code is unfamiliar (value converters, binding) and we'll provide an explanation.

Comment: It is not working, although I am not sure if I did it right. Basically I set the Visibility.Collapsed to one of the D3 plotters. but the other one does not take over the space. The class, VisibilityToHeightConverter, is not called either. I am attaching some code in my meain thread so you can take a look. Thanks.

Comment: Any idea how I should change this?

Comment: I will look at your code (was out to lunch), but I think you should accept Kevin Frei's answer—it works and is simpler.

Comment: For Kevin's solution, I got "Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Research.DynamicDataDisplay.ChartPlotter' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.RowDefinition'.  Error at object 'Microsoft.Research.DynamicDataDisplay.ChartPlotter' in markup file 'FileWatcherCaller;component/view/signalstatsdisplay.xaml'."

Comment: Strange. It works fine for Rectangles. Currently downloading the ChartPlotter to check it out.

Comment: OK. A lot of appreciation. New with WPF:(

Comment: For Kevin's solution: I no longer get the error, but still, it does not change the height of the plot as expected. The top graph still takes only half of the window.

Comment: It helped me thank you so much..uniformGrid orientation is fixed so it is not helpful for my case as I want horizontal orientation.Your solution helped me